# How can I have a verticall middle content and fixed bottom footer?

Tags: html, css

I have this

```
<body>
<div>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="wrapper-content">
     </div>

     <footer>
     </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<body>
```

I'd like to have wrapper-content vertically middle and the footer always fixed at the bottom of the page?

Comment: show your existing css

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
.wrapper {
height: 200px;
width: 500px;
}

.wrapper-content {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
}

.footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you would need to use css to do that. In your css file, make a new ID selector for the wrapper and another one for the footer one: `<div id="wrapper">`, and in the css file add this code:

```
#wrapper{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:400px;
}
```

for the footer, add another id in the css:

```
#footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:50px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If `#wrapper-content` is fixed in height, you are in luck:

```
#wrapper-content
{
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px; /* minus 1/2 times the height */
}
```

If the height can vary, you can vertically center its content using `display: table-cell`:

```
#wrapper
{
    display: table;
}

#wrapper-content
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

For the footer, use absolute or fixed positioning:

```
footer
{
    position: absolute; /* or fixed */
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```